# How to get the page number of an arbitrary PDF object?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to find the page number of a PDF object using itext's Java API. The following code reads in the PDF file, and gets the object containing the open action. How do I get the page number of that object?

```
PdfReader soPdfItext = null;
      try {
        soPdfItext = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Temp\\sample.pdf"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        /* barf here */
      }
      /* Get the catalog */
      PdfDictionary soCatalog = soPdfItext.getCatalog();
      /* Get the object referring to the open action */
      PRIndirectReference soOpenActionReference = (PRIndirectReference) soCatalog.get(PdfName.OPENACTION);
     /* Get the actual object containing the open action */
     PdfObject soOpenActionObject = originalPdfItext.getPdfObject(soOpenActionReference.getNumber());
```

Now what? There is a class Document that contains a method getPageNumber(), but I'm not sure if a) it's relevant to what I want to do and b) if it is relevant, how to implement.

Comment: Have you tried using the getPageNumber method? What values does it return?

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding this class `Document`. Could you provide a link? (It doesn't seem to be either of the default Java API `Document` classes and I don't see a `Document` class on the iText API either.)

Comment: Usually (but not always), the `/OpenAction` referes to another object: a *destination*. The destination object contains the page *index* and one of the available `/Fit*` options. If you want to receive an actual *page number*, you will need to check `/PageLabels` to convert the zero-based index. This can be found in the PDF Reference but you'll going to have to translate it into iText functions...

Comment: To River: I found the documentation for the Document class [here](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html). To Jongware, thank you for the hint. Will give it a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

There are no such things as page numbers in a PDF. Pages are part of a page tree. This page tree consists of `/Pages` elements (the branches of the tree) and `/Page` elements (the leaves of the tree). The page index is calculated by traversing the different branches and leaves of the tree. Optionally, a PDF also defines `/PageLabels`. If you know the page index and if you have the definition of the page labels, you can derive the page number.

You are extracting an `PdfObject` that represents an open action. It can be a `PdfDictionary` or a `PdfArray`.

**PdfDictionary**

If the `PdfObject` is an instance of a `PdfDictionary`, then you need to look at the `/S` item of this dictionary to find out which type of action will be triggered.

- That action could be some JavaScript. If that JavaScript contains an action that jumps to a specific page, there might be a page number in that method.
- That action could be a `GoTo` action, in which case you need to look at the `/D` entry for the *destination* (*).

There are 20 possible types of actions, and actions can be *chained*, so it's up to you to loop through the action chain and to examine every possible action.

This is an example:

```
/OpenAction<</D[8 0 R/Fit]/S/GoTo>>
```

The `<<` and `>>` indicate that the open action is described using a dictionary. The `/S` shows that you have a `/GoTo` action and `/D` describes the destination.

**PdfArray**

If the `PdfAction` is an instance of a `PdfArray`, then this array is a *destination* (*).

This is an example:

```
/OpenAction[6 0 R/XYZ 0 806 0]
```

**Destination**

A destination is an array that consists of a variable number of elements. These are some examples:

```
[8 0 R/Fit]
[6 0 R/XYZ 0 806 0]
```

The first example is an array with two elements `8 0 R` and `/Fit`. The second example is an array with four elements `6 0 R`, `/XYZ`, `0`, `806` and `0`. You need the first element. It doesn't give you the page number (because there is no such thing as page numbers), but it gives you a reference to the `/Page` object. Based on that reference, you can deduce the page number by looping over the page tree and comparing the object number of a specific page with the object number in the destination.

P.S. the other elements are explained in my answer to this question: [iTextPDF hyperlink not linking to the right place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30378537/itextpdf-hyperlink-not-linking-to-the-right-place)

Comment: Yes, the page *index* is calculated and based on this index and the page labels, you can get the page number. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Bruno, thank you for that response. I see the tree root in the catalog, and all the `/Pages` and `/Page` leaves. I spent all morning traversing a few PDFs' trees, landing on the required object, and determining the page number. It works every time!